# Styled Components - Conditionally render an entire css block based on props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, css-in-js

I understand that styles can be conditionally rendered such as:

```
const HelloWorldLabel= styled("div")<{ centered?: boolean }>`
  display: ${({ centered }) => (centered ? "block" : "flex")};;
  margin: ${({ centered }) => (centered ? "auto 0" : "unset")};
  padding: ${({ centered }) => (centered ? "0 15px" : "unset")};
`;
```

This does not look DRY - How can I (is it possible) render an **entire block** of css styles based on props?

Something like:

```
const HelloWorldLabel= styled("div")<{ centered?: boolean }>`
   if (centered) {
    display: "block" ;
    margin: $"auto 0";
     padding: "0 15px" ;
   } else {
     ......
   }
`;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `styled-component`, or any CSS-in-JS, you can conditionally render a [`css` block](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#css):

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

const light = css`
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
`;

const dark = css`
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
`;

const Box = styled.div`
  ${({ isDark }) => (isDark ? light : dark)}
`;
```

---

Full Example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

const light = css`
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: black;
`;

const dark = css`
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
`;

const FlexBox = styled.div`
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  ${({ isDark }) => (isDark ? light : dark)}
`;

const App = () => {
  const [isDark, setIsDark] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setIsDark(b => !b);

  return (
    <FlexBox isDark={isDark}>
      <div>Some Text</div>
      <button onClick={toggle}>Change Block</button>
    </FlexBox>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Edit zen-https-5bkm5]

Comment: Just to add on to the above, my team has also found this utility to be very helpful for readability: https://github.com/yldio/styled-is#usage

Comment: This works great and definitely easy on the eyes for readability.

Answer (score 2):

A less verbose way that worked for me is

```js
const SideMenu = styled.aside`
  width: 200px;
  ${({ isHidden }) => isHidden && `
      display: none;
    `}
  // another random prop you need here
  ${({ redBg }) => redBg && `
    background-color: red;
  `}
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function and return the css based on prop:

```
const HelloWorldLabel= styled("div")`
  ${({centered}) => {
    if (centered) {
      return `
       display: "block" ;
       margin: "auto 0";
       padding: "0 15px";
      `
    } else {
      return `// Other styles here`
    }
   }}
`;
```

Comment: Note that with this solution, you returning a string literal, therefore you won't get auto-complete if you working with css-in-js plugins.

Comment: this is definitely an option, thank you for posting this answer as well!

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is

```
let customCss = setCustomCss(position) => {
let positionCss = {
center: [ 'css: value;', 'css:value;'],
left: .....
right: ....
}

return   return positionCss[position];

}
  let HelloWorldLabel= styled('div')(customCss, {
    /* css common to all */
  })
```